# Retain the message in the textbox when the checkbox is still checked

Tags: c#, .net

I have 3 checkboxes with corresponding message in a textbox. My teacher wants the message to remain in the textbox when the checkbox is still checked and hide the text when it is unchecked. In my case when I checked the 3 checkboxes their 3 corresponding messages will appear but when I unchecked one of the checkboxes and the other two are still checked, all the message will disappear. My problem is when I unchecked one of the checkbox and and the other 2 are still checked the corresponding messages with the remaining two checked checkboxes will remain in their textboxes.

```
private void chkCarWheels_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkCarWheels.Checked == true)
        lblMessage.Text = lblMessage.Text + mycar.hasWheels(4);
    else
        lblMessage.Text = "My  " + txtName.Text + " Car";
}

private void chkCarAcceleration_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkCarAcceleration.Checked == true)
       lblMessage.Text = lblMessage.Text + mycar.Accelerate();
    else
        lblMessage.Text = "My  " + txtName.Text + " Car";
} 

private void chkCarBreakpad_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkCarBreakpad.Checked == true)
        lblMessage.Text = lblMessage.Text + mycar.hasBreak();
    else
        lblMessage.Text = "My  " + txtName.Text + " Car";
}
```

Comment: It is doing exactly what you are telling it to do in the else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to create message depending on checkboxes states. You can create method, which will do the job and call it when state of some checkbox changed.

```
private void chkCarWheels_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BuildMessage();
}

private void chkCarAcceleration_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BuildMessage();
} 

private void chkCarBreakpad_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BuildMessage();
}
```

Or the better one - *create one event handler for all checkboxes*:

```
// use for chkCarWheels, chkCarAcceleration, chkCarBreakpad
private void chkCar_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BuildMessage();
}

private void BuildMessage()
{     
    lblMessage.Text = "My  " + txtName.Text + " Car";
    if (chkCarWheels.Checked)
        lblMessage.Text = lblMessage.Text + mycar.hasWheels(4);
    if (chkCarAcceleration.Checked)
       lblMessage.Text = lblMessage.Text + mycar.Accelerate();
    if (chkCarBreakpad.Checked)
       lblMessage.Text = lblMessage.Text + mycar.hasBreak();
}
```

You don't need to compare boolean values with true/false. Use those values directly `if (chkCarWheels.Checked)`. And keep in mind that in C# we use CamelCase names form methods. Also consider to use `StringBuilder` to build whole message and then assign it to label:

```
private void BuildMessage()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat("My {0} Car", txtName.Text);
    if (chkCarWheels.Checked)
        sb.Append(mycar.hasWheels(4));
    if (chkCarAcceleration.Checked)
       sb.Append(mycar.Accelerate());
    if (chkCarBreakpad.Checked)
       sb.Append((mycar.hasBreak());
    lblMessage.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private void chkCarWheels_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chkCar();
    }

    private void chkCarAcceleration_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chkCar();
    } 

    private void chkCarBreakpad_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       chkCar()
    } 



private void chkCar()
{

string msg="";

if (chkCarWheels.Checked)
msg=msg+mycar.hasWheels(4);

if(chkCarAcceleration.Checked)
msg=msg+mycar.Accelerate();

if(chkCarBreakpad.Checked)
msg=msg+mycar.hasBreak();

lblMessage.Text=msg;

}
```